# How to improve foreach within foreach

Tags: c#

I have a foreach loop within foreach loop which looks like this:

```
// Item is an abstract class. Item1, Item2, etc. are his heirs.
List<Item> allItems = new List<Item> { new Item1(), new Item2(), new Item3(), new Item4() };
List<Type> affectedItems = new List<Type> { typeof(Item1), typeof(Item3) };

foreach(Item i in allItems)
    foreach(Type t in affectedItems)
        if(i.GetType().Equals(t))
        {
            // does something
        }
```

How can I improve my code so inner loop would not waste so much time checking for nonexistent items in a list?

Comment: You can use linq, but internally that will also do a `foreach foreach`, so same performance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Any linq extension method you use (eg `Where`, `Any`) is an extra loop.

You need to minimize the number of loops (especially the nested ones), in your case the best way is to use a fast lookup data structure:

```
List<Item> allItems = new List<Item>{ new Item1(), new Item2(), new Item3(), new Item4() };

HashSet<Type> affectedItems = new HashSet<Type>(){ typeof(Item1), typeof(Item3) };

foreach (Item i in allItems)
{
    if (affectedItems.Contains(i.GetType()))
    {
        // Do Something
    }
}
```

This is the fastest approach so far with minimal loops and takes up to **0.02 milliseconds**, while other methods take up to **0.7**.

**A quick advise**, whenever you have Loop up process and you want to optimize look for data structures to use like `HashSet`, `Dictionary`, `Lookup`, etc..

Comment: Albeit this is what I would do, for extra cleanliness I'd do: `foreach (Item i in allItems.Where(x => affectedItems.Contains(x.GetType()))` instead of the extra `if` inside. More likely no performance change and you'd remove a level of nesting

Answer (score 2):

Write single loop like this:

```
foreach (Item i in allItems.Where (item => affectedItems.
    Any (type => type.Equals (item.GetType ()))))
```

This will return only items from `allItems` that are type from `affectedItems`.

The only difference from your code is that `Any` will stop searching after first type is found. That's the only improvement. But you can add `break` in your `if` statement. Then these two code snippets would be equivalent.

Comment: So here we have 3 loops instead of 2. One `foreach`, one `Where` and one `Any`. I don't think this will be any better that what the use posted. I think the use can use `break` inside his loop and it will be more readable.

Comment: @user3185569 There's actually 2: `foreach` and `Any`. `Where` is equivalent to `if`.

Comment: `Where` iterate over the entire `IEnumerable` and checks the predicate, that's for sure. I be the performance for this code is worst than the original, just try it.

Comment: @user3185569 But it iterates on the fly. It does not iterated collection in advance.

Comment: After some tests, your method takes up to 0.7 milliseconds. Mine takes 0.01. Check my answer.

Comment: @user3185569 That's because of using `HashSet`

Comment: @akazemis answer uses `HashSet` but it is slower, because it has extra loops.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a large list of types then changing your list to HashSet could help in performance otherwise it doesn't make much difference.

```
List<Item> allItems = new List<Item> { new Item1(), new Item2(), new Item3(), new Item4() };
HashSet<Type> affectedItems = new HashSet<Type> { typeof(Item1), typeof(Item3) };

var items = allItems.Where(item=> affectedItems.Contains(item.GetType())); 
foreach(var item in items)
{
        // does something
}
```

Comment: There are some extra loops where, your method takes up to 0.5 seconds. Check mine, it take up top 0.02 milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

This one was the quickest (I try your code, Linq with intersect and this one):

```
Array.ForEach(allItems.ToArray(), i => {
    var t = i.GetType();
    if (affectedItems.Contains(t)) {
        // Do Something
    }
});
```

Comment: Why converting to an Array when you can just use `allItems.ForEach` directly ? This has 3 loops and not even 2: `ToArray`, `ForEach` and `Contains`.

Comment: You are right - my mistake. I think 2 loops are required because you search betweent to arrays so there is no solution without iterating through them, I think.

Comment: Both ForEach methods looks similar so execution time should be comparable.